# Do a JNDI lookup of rmi service in Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jndi

My problem is that ,  I want to use RMI regitry of Jboss.

To do that, I want to bind the RMI registry to JNDI name and do the lookup from client using the JNDI name.

So first client uses the JNDI name to lookup the rmi service and then uses it.

Let me know if this is possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jnp-client.jar.`

Drop a `jndi.properties` on your classpath with the following info :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

HTH

Comment: Now, how to expose my class using jboss rmi,  so that i can access the class using jndi naming from class

Comment: @rajvirsingh Just `bind()` it via JNDI, as above.